# app.yaml url configs for google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm relatively new to GAE, and I'm having some difficulty understanding the URL mappings.

I have a set of data that is static (HTML templates, login forms, js etc), and a section that's dynamic.

My current app.yaml has as follows:

```
handlers:
- url: /.*
  static_dir: /static
- url: /service/.*
  script: _go_app
  login: required
```

The idea here is that `http://myapp/service/foo` would route to the app, and that anything else like `http://myapp/foo.html` should serve `/static/foo.html`.  However, I'm getting a 404 error on the static request.

Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Static_Directory_Handlers),

> url: A URL prefix. This value uses regular expression syntax (and so regexp special characters must be escaped), but it should not contain groupings. All URLs that begin with this prefix are handled by this handler, using the portion of the URL after the prefix as part of the file path.

In your case since you are specifying `url: /.*`, the prefix will be `foo.html`, and the file to fetch would have an empty filename.

Additionally, the handlers are evaluated from top to bottom so you need to change the order.

```
handlers:
- url: /service/.*
  script: _go_app
  login: required
- url: /
  static_dir: static
```

Answer (score 2):

Order is important so your /service/ handler is likely never going to be called unless you move it above the static handler. Also, the 404s are caused by incorrect syntax in your static declaration. Change your handlers to:

```
handlers:
- url: /service/.*
  script: _go_app
  login: required
- url: /
  static_dir: static
```

Answer (score -1):

A static_dir directive serves files by the name after the prefix that matches the given regular expression. If the RE ends in `.*`, the entire URL will be considered the prefix, so there will be nothing left over to use as the file path.

Try `url: /` instead.

Also, handlers are matched in order.

The regular expression `/.*` matches all URLs you can receive requests for, so anything after it will never match. Put it last.

Comment: I changed per this recommendation, and I'm now getting a different error.  It's still 404, but the log reads: `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\\static\\foo.html'`  I tried putting the "static" directory under the root `<project>/static` and also under where the app scripts are `<project>/hello/static`.  Not sure where the project is rooting....